# TfsConfigurationServer.GetService<VersionControlServer>() always returns null

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to connect to TFS 2010 using TFS SDK, but can't get VersionControlServer service.

```
var servers = RegisteredTfsConnections.GetConfigurationServers(); // ok
```

then

```
var tfs = new TfsConfigurationServer(servers.First().Uri, CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
// or
var tfs = new TfsConfigurationServer(servers.First());
```

both always returns null:

```
var vc = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>(); // null!
```

What should I do?

Comment: did you used to get the 'vc' as null ? The reason I am asking is that I am receiving the similar error.

Comment: It may depend on version of TFS because some API works only for specific version and you must use another API. What version do you run?

Comment: I have TFS2010, does the solution given below work for you ?

Comment: If I remember correctly (it was 3 years ago!) it worked. Otherwise I would not accept it for sure.

Comment: I used the solution provided below, I still get the output of version control as null.

Comment: @RamMehta : the TfsTeamprojectCollection.GetService<T>() stuff will ALSO fail silently (eg: simply return null) when there are imperfections in the app.config - if you leave out the <appSettings/> parent node for the <add/> nodes within <configuration/> for instance.the rest of .Net all runs fine but the TfsTeamProjectCollection instance demonstrates strange behaviour (including not returning any services).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't want the configuration server, you want the project collection. The version control service is scoped to a team project collection. For example:

```
var projectCollection =
    TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(registeredProjectCollection);

var versionControl = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```

See also: [Connect to a Project Collection](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Connect%20to%20Project%20Collection&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: Where can I get default collection name? (I know nothing about current TFS, I want to get it from current context)

Comment: Yes, that's right. That will get the collections that are registered with the Team Explorer client on the machine.

Comment: @JimLamb I tried doing this same , but I am still getting "versionControl" as Null, any solutions to that ?  Any more details do you need to help me ?

Comment: @RamMehta what version of TFS (server & client) are you using? Do you have a code sample you can share?

Comment: @JimLamb We have a 2010 version of the server and I have been coding in VS2012. Does coding in VS2012 make any difference ?