# Alerts for Changeset changes?

Tags: tfs

So in Team Foundation there are a variety of alerts for things like build completion, build status changed, etc. But there doesn't seem to be one for changesets being modified. Does anybody know of any extension or something that would do this?

Really I just need to make a SOAP call to a web service when a changeset is updated (so that the website can get the changeset data again). I have already done this successfully for the Build Completion alert, but recently I realized that changes to changesets also need to be tracked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute code on TFS server after a user checks in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605479/how-to-execute-code-on-tfs-server-after-a-user-checks-in-code)

Comment: How are the changesets being modified?

Comment: @John Saunders Usually just the check-in comment is changed.

Comment: I'm not sure there is such an event. It's not something that's done frequently.