# TFS ServerItemExists method of versionControlServer returns file not exists, while it is present

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm trying to update in-house developed plugin for Azure DevOps Server. Previously company was using TFS 2017, and plugin worked correctly. Now, it launches (I see it through messages in EventLog), but there is an issue, that function ServerItemExists returns "False", but actually file is present.

I have found issues about that versionControl TfsConfigurationServer.GetService() always returns null
([TfsConfigurationServer.GetService<VersionControlServer>() always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098814/tfsconfigurationserver-getserviceversioncontrolserver-always-returns-null)), but it seems to be not my case. Here code below

```
            var configFileServerPath = $"$/{projectName}/AutoCodeReview.xml";
                        var versionControlServer = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

                        writeLog(EventLogEntryType.Information, $"Details. configFileServerPath: {configFileServerPath}. versionControlServer.TeamProjectCollection.Name: {versionControlServer.TeamProjectCollection.Name}");
                        bool ItemExists = versionControlServer.ServerItemExists(configFileServerPath, ItemType.File);
                        writeLog(EventLogEntryType.Information, $"Item existence: {ItemExists}");
                        if (!ItemExists)
                        {
                            writeLog(EventLogEntryType.Information, $"return, not item exists");
                            return null;
                        }
```

So I use EventViewer as smth like debug output, and I see, that I've got message as "Item existence false". But file exists!

My suggestions in path defining.
URL in browser to element looks like this: http://tfs1:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project1/_versionControl?path=%24%2FProject1%2FAutoCodeReview.xml

As I figure out by EventVwr, these are paths:

`configFileServerPath $/Project1/AutoCodeReview.xml`

`TeamProjectCollection.Name http://tfs1:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/`

So this works fine in TFS 2017, and shows that there is no file in Azure DevOps Server 2019. As I new to C#, it seems to be difficult to realize what is wrong.

Comment: Can you use the new TFS (Auzre DevOps Server) API? (now you use the old)

Comment: Hmm, maybe it the point. Actually, rewriting code maybe expensive... anyway, I'll study this area. Thanks

Comment: The old API should working in 2019, but it's good to move the new :) I don't have here TFS 2019 to check the old :/